# Change iOS App icon at build time

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, icons

I've came across these tutorials ([1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/105641/change-app-icon-build-time) and [2](http://merowing.info/2013/03/overlaying-application-version-on-top-of-your-icon/)), but struggling to make them work. The first one is more verbose so I followed it step by step. Script is running with no errors, but app icon is not changing.

Here's what I have so far:

```
IFS=$'\n'
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
versionNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
commit=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
echo buildNumber=$buildNumber
echo versionNumber=$versionNumber
echo commit=$commit
echo branch=$branch
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin

function generateIcon () {
    BASE_IMAGE_NAME=$1
    TARGET_PATH=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}
    echo TARGET_PATH=$TARGET_PATH
    echo SRCROOT=$SRCROOT
    BASE_IMAGE_PATH=$(find ${SRCROOT} -name ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME})
    WIDTH=$(identify -format %w ${BASE_IMAGE_PATH})
    echo WIDTH=$WIDTH
    FONT_SIZE=$(echo "$WIDTH * .15" | bc -l)
    echo FONT_SIZE=$FONT_SIZE

    convert dev_ribbon.png -resize $WIDTHx$WIDTH resizedRibbon.png
    convert ${BASE_IMAGE_PATH} -fill white -font Times-Bold -pointsize ${FONT_SIZE} -gravity south -annotate 0 "$buildNumber" - | composite resizedRibbon.png - ${TARGET_PATH}
}

echo "Generating new icons ..."
generateIcon "app_icon_57.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_72.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_76.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_57@2x.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_72@2x.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_60@2x.png"
generateIcon "app_icon_76@2x.png"
```

Every variable has the correct value, but nothing happens. I've tried to change some images using terminal command to see if tools working correctly - they do.

I'm out of ideas why it's not working.

The last idea I have is my build script might execute at the wrong point. Where it should be placed in script sequence?
Or it outputs images to the wrong place.

I'm using xcassets for the app icon.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get the App Icon to change at Build Time?

Comment: @chrisP Yeah, I ended up with a slightly different approach. I'll try to post an answer today. Thanks for reminding about this post.